# Effectiveness of parallel model training for neural_network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model, scikit-learn

I am planning to parallelize the model training of **multilayer perceptron** using `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` in conjunction with any distributed-memory framework, specifically Message Passing Interface (MPI). This is because I will be having a very large dataset as an input and would like to speed up the training time.

My idea is to divide the dataset into subsets and distribute them among the available processors such that each processor independently trains the received subset. At the end, each processor will return the weight vector where both are sum up in the master processor to be the final weight vector from the entire dataset.

How effective is this approach? Does it make sense?

Comment: You're describing a form of bagging.  Neural networks are inherently serial, but attempts to parallelize them have been tried look into "hogwild".   If the constraint is the size of the data, look into minibatch gradient descent.  This updates the weight vector based on gradient updates computed over random subsets of the data.  If you are after speed and want to attain speed by massive parallelization, see whether a random forest might not work for you -- those are much better-suited to parallelization